# Get TS Type of Vue component prop

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In Vue3, given a component `ChildComponent.vue`:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{
  text: string;
}>();
</script>
```

And another component `ParentComponent.vue`

```js
<template>
  <ChildComponent :text="myText" />
</template>

<script script setup lang="ts">
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent'
const myText = ref("hello")
</script>
```

I want to create a TS Type that is "dynamically" tied to the prop `text`.
Kind of like how `ReturnType<>` works for functions, but I want it for props.

So my code would work like this made-up code.

```js
<script script setup lang="ts">
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent'
type TextProp = TypeOfProp<ChildComponent.props.text> // TypeOfProp<ChildComponent.props.text> = string
const myText = ref<TextProp>("hello")
</script>
```

Why do I want to do this?: I want autocompletion on the `myText` ref.